# Get the sum of horizontal margins/paddings

Tags: android

I have a nested LinearLayout (or other type of layout), and I would just like to sum up all the horizontal values of margins/paddings of this view and its parent and potentially grandparents and so on.

I just need the **clean width** of this Layout which will be `window width minus all horizontal margins/paddings`.

I've started like that:

```
private int sumMargins(View view) {
    LayoutParams params = (LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
    int margins = params.leftMargin + params.rightMargin + view.getPaddingStart() + view.getPaddingEnd();

    ViewParent parent = view.getParent();
    while (parent != null) {
        // here I need to recursively gather all nested parents margins/paddings 
        // (add them to the `margins` variable)
    }

    return margins;
}
```

Comment: `clean width of this Layout` ? how does it differ from `width - leftPadding - rightPadding` ?

Comment: The idea is to get a clean width of this layout compared to the width of the screen. This layout can be inside multiply nested parents which may also have horizontal margins/paddings. I want to sum all of them (if they exist).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams` will give you access to the margins of a view. The following code will follow the hierarchy of views up to the top-level `DecorView` and sum left/right margins and padding.

```
private int sumMargins(View view) {
    ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams marginParams;
    int margins = 0;
    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();

    while (view != null && view != decorView) {
        marginParams = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
        if (marginParams != null) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
                margins += marginParams.getMarginStart() + marginParams.getMarginEnd() +
                        view.getPaddingStart() + view.getPaddingEnd();
            } else {
                margins += marginParams.leftMargin + marginParams.rightMargin +
                        view.getPaddingLeft() + view.getPaddingRight();
            }
        }
        view = (View) view.getParent();
    }

    return margins;
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks